# Is there an App or Widget that can replace my Screen On and Off Button on my Moto Droid?

Tags: screen, buttons

The button is broken and I'm waiting for my replacement phone.  I can turn it on by sliding open the keyboard but I have to wait for it to sleep to turn the screen off.  Is there an app or a shortcut that I can put on the home screen to do this? Or maybe a hack to change my camera button to a screen off button?  It's an un-rooted Motorola Droid 1 running 2.2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up using this free app: http://code.google.com/p/lockenabler/ and with smart bar I was able to set the camera button as a shortcut. My cam button now turns off the screen on a long press.

Answer (score 1):

There was an app reviewed by "Android Guys" yesterday call screen off , unfortunately its not free and costs 99 cents , here is the [link](http://www.androidguys.com/2010/09/14/app-review-screen-2/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I hate to be a cheapskate over a $1 app but I actually found a free one in the comments on that review: http://code.google.com/p/lockenabler/