# Are there any apps that can shut down the phone?

Tags: motorola-droid, power-on

The power button is stuck on my friend's phone, so he wanted to know if there were any apps available that could shut off the phone, or any other way to turn it off without pressing the power button. He has a Droid with Android 2.2.2

Comment: Check out the answer to this question: http://android.stackexchange.com/q/367/137

Comment: @Matt: isn't power button different than sleep/lock button?

Comment: @Lie: No one button on the OG Droid does both (Normally: Press to sleep and long press to power down)  but it's a good point that those two functions are different.

Comment: @MatrixFrog:  I reopened the question.  Are you trying to just turn the screen off (sleep) or power down the phone so it's completely off?

Comment: Matt: I'm not sure what he wants exactly, but I'll make sure he sees this question and hopefully some part of your answer will help him out. Thanks!

Comment: Just a curiosity...
How are you supposed to turn it on again without a power button? O_O

Answer (score 6):

1. If you are simply trying to turn the screen off, like the normal single press of the power button on the Droid does refer to this question: [Is there an App or Widget that can replace my Screen On and Off Button on my Moto Droid?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/367/is-there-an-app-or-widget-that-can-replace-my-screen-on-and-off-button-on-my-moto)
2. If you are trying to power down the phone you'll need to have a rooted Droid then you can install an app that give you a boot menu like [Quick Boot](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.siriusapplications.quickboot) or [Reboot Manager](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.raue.rebootwidget), both of wich give you an option to turn the phone off.

Comment: As I pointed out in the answer you do need a rooted device for option 2. Option 1 does not require root access.