# Long press home button and power button both showing power menu?

Tags: root-access, 4.3-jelly-bean, samsung-galaxy-note-2

Yesterday i installed the official rom for my note 2 (N7100DDUEML4), and after that i rooted the phone. But After that power button and the long press home button both shows the power menu.

> I am unable to see the recent apps popup

How can i fix this or is there any way i can change the behaviour of long press home button as my phone is rooted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your device is rooted, [Button Remapper](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/12644/16575) might provide a solution. It allows you to re-assing actions triggered by buttons, so you should be able to re-map the home key accordingly.

Comment: It did the trick